# Is it bad to ask for an internship offer extension when considering a different company?

Tags: job-offer, internship

So I have an internship offer for Company A that is going to expire soon. However, I'm currently working part-time at Company B and am also wanting to explore internship options there.

While I am certainty interested in Company A, I'm not sure it's a place I would like to work at full-time in the future due to it's geographical location away from family. It would be a great internship, but at this point, I'd like to take an internship somewhere I see myself working at.

Unfortunately, Company B has just started their hiring process and I am waiting to hear back from different applications right now. There's a very slim chance that I will get an offer from Company B before the offer deadline passes.... But it's my only other internship offer at this point. So my question is the following:

Is it rude to ask for an internship offer extension when considering another company? If I did email and ask for an extension, should I be vague about the reason or be upfront and say that I am still interviewing with other companies?

**EDIT** To clarify, I'm asking for an internship offer deadline extension from Company A. Regarding the duplicate, I don't want to ask a general question about how to delay acceptance, I was more wondering about specific extension request advice in the case I would do that.

Comment: You are currently working part-time at Company B as an intern? When you say: "ask for an interniship extension", you are talking about your current company or the offer from Company A?

Comment: From the linked post: "stalling is not the tactic to take - there's always another *you* out there ... be honest with everyone involved". If the alternative is declining, there isn't much harm in just *asking* whether an extension is possible.

Comment: @Dukeling Thanks for the linked post! I was also asking for any advice on what to include in the extension request (i.e the reason, timeframe, etc) so I'm not sure that post answers those questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not bad to consider it, or to ask, but you shouldn't lie about why (if they say "sure" and don't ask why, it's not bad to not volunteer if they don't care to ask).

If they decline to extend it, and I doubt they they would if they did know the reason, then it would be very, very bad to accept one if you intend to cast it aside for another.

1) You are making a commitment to that company, and they are making one for you.

2) You are holding onto a slot that some other prospective intern could use to help their own career, which they may not be able to recoup after the normal process windows have closed.

It's fine to apply for both, but if the deadline arrives before company "B" has reached their decision point, then you need to either decline company "A"'s offer, or withdraw from company "B"'s.  Once you reach the deadline date, you have to choose.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Didn't know it was okay to ask without giving a reason.

Comment: @ocean800 - you could be vague, I suppose -  "I still have a couple things up in the air that I need to figure out."  There can be a ton of reasons why someone might ask for a little more time.